# how to randomly pick an object from a hashmap in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to randomly pick a `(key, value)` object from a `hashmap` in `kotlin`. I have below `hashmap` created.

```
val tips = hashMapOf("Having a balanced diet is the key" to "Have nutritious foods like vegetables and fruits along with legumes, whole wheat, cereals etc."
            , "Fluids will help you manage" to "Drink sufficient water and fluids to maintain the retention of water in your body."
            , "Do not miss prenatal supplements" to "Doctors prescribe prenatal vitamin and mineral supplements for the normal growth and development."
            , "Folic acid is essential" to "During pregnancy, have folic acid (supplement) or folate (natural source of folic acid) to avoid various health problems.")
```

I want to randomly get the `(key, value)` object from the `hashmap`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the best way is by generating a random number and then access that specific number in the list

```
val random = Random() 
tips.entries.elementAt(random.nextInt(tips.size))
```

You can also do something like (not recommended):

```
tips.entries.shuffled().first()
```

**NOTE :**

> import kotlin.collections.shuffled

Comment: there is no method called `shuffled()`

Comment: you need to import it :
import kotlin.collections.shuffled

Comment: It's a bad idea to shuffle the entire collection only to pick the first element. @jrtapsell's answer is much better.

Comment: (unless the shuffle is lazy, but this one isn't).

Comment: Shuffled works better for cases where you need all the items shuffled, like a deck of cards you draw from, whereas the random method I used is better if you only need a single card, as it only has to pick one random number and lookup by it

Comment: kotlin has a random selector over selections so you can just do `tips.entries.random()`

Answer (score 5):

## Using an extension function

```
val tips = hashMapOf("Having a balanced diet is the key" to "Have nutritious foods like vegetables and fruits along with legumes, whole wheat, cereals etc."
        , "Fluids will help you manage" to "Drink sufficient water and fluids to maintain the retention of water in your body."
        , "Do not miss prenatal supplements" to "Doctors prescribe prenatal vitamin and mineral supplements for the normal growth and development."
        , "Folic acid is essential" to "During pregnancy, have folic acid (supplement) or folate (natural source of folic acid) to avoid various health problems.")

val random = Random()

fun <T,U> Map<T,U>.random(): Map.Entry<T,U> = entries.elementAt(random.nextInt(size))

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(tips.random())
}
```

This works for any map kind, and even if items are added to the map.